# SSAS - Time Intelligence is not working in Tabular Model

Tags: ssas, tabular, dax, bism

I have a separate date dimension marked as Date table in Tabular Model and having proper relationship with another table(e.g SalesTable) with column of date type. But still time intelligence functions are not working. I am using the date column from other table (e.g SalesTable) in the formula.

I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong in our tabular model. Can someone give any insights?

Thanks,

Vishal Jharwade

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the date column from your date table in your formulas. For example

```
PrevMonthAmount:=CALCULATE(SUM([Amount]),PREVIOUSMONTH('Date'[Date]))
```

Also, time intelligence doesn't work in direct query mode, on the chance that you are using that mode.

This is a good intro to time intelligence:http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3075/sql-server-analysis-service-dax-time-intelligence/